# Nesting a DynamicMap inside a DynamicMap is not supported

Tags: python-3.x, plot, holoviews, dynamic-mapping

I have different timeseries plot for different time series i made holomap , now i am plotting different lat lon range holomap then i am getting exception :- 
Exception: Nesting a DynamicMap inside a DynamicMap is not supported. Ensure that the DynamicMap callback returns an Element or (Nd)Overlay. If you have applied an operation ensure it is not dynamic by setting dynamic=False.

:DynamicMap   [Lat and Lon :]
   :DynamicMap   [Date and Time :]
I am not getting plot as nesting of dynamicmap ,

I have tried to make rasterize at last final plot . it didn't work

```
    latlon_selPLot={f'lat:{k[0]} lon:{k[1]}':finalplot(k) for k in 
    [[(12,15),(80,85)],[(13,18),(81,95)]]}
    dd=df_div.opts(width=200, height=100)
    hmap11 = hv.HoloMap(latlon_selPLot, kdims='Lat and Lon :' )
    tiles*rasterize(hmap11)



 # Below is the code i am using , where i have to make change , 
 # so that i get holomap of lat_lon_selPlot when i select one 
 #lat_lon range then that particular area plot is shown .


 allplot={k.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"):plotthis(k)for k in 
 perdelta(strt, strt + timedelta(days=1), timedelta(hours=18))}
 allplot2={k.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"):plotsecond(k)for k in 
 perdelta(strt, strt + timedelta(days=1), timedelta(hours=18))}
 ....

 tiles = gv.tile_sources.Wikipedia
 hmap1 = hv.HoloMap(allplot, kdims='Date and Time :' )
 hmap2 = hv.HoloMap(allplot2, kdims='Date and Time :')

def finalplot(rng):

        finalplot=rasterize(hmap1.redim.range(Latitude=rng[0], 
        Longitude=rng[1])).options(**opts)*hmap2
        return finalplot

latlon_selPLot={f'lat:{k[0]} lon:{k[1]}':finalplot(k) for k in 
[[(12,15),(80,85)],[(13,18),(81,95)]]}
dd=df_div.opts(width=200, height=100)
hmap11 = hv.HoloMap(latlon_selPLot, kdims='Lat and Lon :' )
tiles*hmap11
```

I want my lat_lon_selPlot holomap also work .

Answer (score 1):

For selecting only the selected lat lon range i am doing another process of panel.select.
but first select.value is getting selected and when i change the select.value of another then the plot is not getting changed. 
where i am doing wrong ? how i can link with jlink , is my jlink correct ?

```
tiles = gv.tile_sources.Wikipedia
hmap1 = hv.HoloMap(allplot, kdims='Date and Time :' )
hmap2 = hv.HoloMap(allplot2, kdims='Date and Time :')
finalplot=tiles*rasterize(hmap1).options(**opts)*hmap2
dd=df_div.opts(width=200, height=100)

select = pn.widgets.Select(name='States', options=['TN','AP', 'Odisha'])
 latmin = [7, 13, 19]
 latmax = [14, 19, 22]
 longmin = [77, 79, 85]
 longmax = [83, 85, 88]
if (select.value=='TN'):
    hhmap = rasterize(hmap1.redim.range(Latitude=(latmin[0],latmax[0]), Longitude= 
 (longmin[0], longmax[0])))
   select.jslink(finalplot, value='object')
    finalplot=tiles*hhmap*hmap2

 elif (select.value=='AP'):
      hhmap =rasterize(hmap1.redim.range(Latitude=(latmin[1],latmax[1]), Longitude= 
 (longmin[1], longmax[1]))).options(**opts)
   select.jslink(finalplot, value='object')
    finalplot=tiles*rasterize(hhmap)*hmap2

else:
    hhmap = rasterize(hmap1.redim.range(Latitude=(latmin[2],latmax[2]), Longitude= 
   (longmin[2], longmax[2]))).options(**opts)
    select.jslink(finalplot, value='Odisha')
    finalplot=tiles*rasterize(hhmap)*hmap2
 # else:
 #     tiles*rasterize(hmap1).options(**opts)*hmap2

 finalplot=tiles*rasterize(hhmap).options(**opts)*hmap2
  finalplot=pn.Column(dd, finalplot, select).servable()    
  # finalplot=pn.Column(dd, finalplot).servable()
 finalplot
```

How i can link up another select.value options , so that different plot come when select.value change ?

Answer (score 0):

`rasterize` is a so called dynamic operation, which means that it returns a DynamicMap which updates whenever one of its streams changes. In the case of `rasterize` this allows it to update whenever the range of your plot changes. If you do not want the dynamic behavior you have to specify `dynamic=False` in the rasterize call, in your case that means you will have:

```
def finalplot(rng):
    return rasterize(hmap1, x_range=rng[1], y_range=[0], dynamic=False).options(**opts)*hmap2
```

That said it looks like you would still have nested HoloMaps in that case. To resolve that you will then have to call `.collate``

```
hmap11 = hv.HoloMap(latlon_selPLot, kdims='Lat and Lon :' ).collate()
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for quick reply ,
Actually i want that dynamic feature as i want to change the data dynamically when i do zoom in .

Comment: Is there any way else ? To get plot of particular lat lon range with dropdown option except holomap ?